# What do you feel right now?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, difference

A vietnamese woman in a TV show asked a candidate '**what do you feel right now?**'. I wonder what this sentence means. I think she should have asked **'how do you feel right now'** instead but some people say these two sentences have the same meaning while some say the first sentence is used for asking about the state of health. I need some explanations from native speakers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the two questions can be interchangeable. But strictly speaking, they are slightly different.

"What do you feel?" is more specific, like "which emotion are you feeling?"

It can also be used in the physical aspect. A doctor might ask "what do you feel?" expecting a response about which sensations you may be feeling (pain, tingling, etc).

"How do you feel?" is more general. The expected response is more about whether you feel good or bad or somewhere in between.